# Pegar o id de uma lista do banco de dados, e usar em outra pagina para inserir telefones em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Olá pessoal estou fazendo um teste, e eu tenho os dados em uma tabela na minha pagina do index em HTML e pretendo clicar em um botão na frente de algum dado e em seguida me encaminhar para uma outra pagina que mostrara o nome da pessoa que eu cliquei e inserir telefones na outra tabela que eu tenho.

Inicialmente não sei como pegar o nome da pessoa que eu clicar pra usar na pagina adicionatel.php, alguém me ajude.
Obrigado.

```html
<table id="test" class="text-center">
                    <caption>Dados da Tabela Pessoa</caption>
                    <tr><td><h4>ID</h4></td><td><h4>Nome</h4></td><td><h4>CPF</h4></td></tr>
                    <?php
                    
                    $selbanco = "SELECT * FROM pessoa";
                    $querybanc = mysql_query($selbanco);
                    
                    //$conta = mysql_num_rows($querybanc); //essa funçao conta quantas linhas tem na tabela do banco
                    
                    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($querybanc)){
                        
                        $id = $linha['id'];
                        $nomee = $linha['nome'];
                        $cpff = $linha['cpf'];
                        
                        //echo "$id $nomee $cpff <br>";
                ?>
                    <tr><td><?php echo "$id"; ?></td><td><?php echo "$nomee"; ?></td><td><?php echo "$cpff"; ?></td>
                        <td><a href="adicionatel.php" class="btn btn-success">Adicionar telefone de contato</a><?php } ?></td></tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Você pode passar no link assim `adicionatel.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>` ai na pagina `adicionatel.php` você busca os dados da pessoa pelo `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu link coloque assim

```
<a href="adicionatel.php?id=<?=$id?>&nome=<?=$nome?>" class="btn btn-success">Adicionar telefone de contato</a>
```

Na sua página adicionatel.php coloque assim...

```
<?php

echo $_GET['id'] . ' - ' . $_GET['nome'];
```

Comment: Obrigado galera me ajudou e resolveu meu problema!  :D

Comment: se puder marcar como correta a resposta eu agradeço. obrigado =)

Comment: Como eu faço para marcar como correta?

Comment: tem um checkzinho em baixo dos pontos..

Comment: não consegui encontrar... :(

Comment: deve ser porque vc não é usuário registrado, mas tudo bem fica tranquilo ;)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode passar a `String nomee` por get vai ficar assim.

```
<a href="adicionatel.php?nome=<?php echo $nomee;?>" class="btn btn-success">Adicionar telefone de contato</a>
```

na sua tela adicionatel.php

você recebe esta `String` assim:

```
$nome=$_GET['nome'];
//e vc pode utilizar a variavel como quiser por ex faz um echo
echo $nome;
```

Answer (score 1):

Passar tudo por get não é a melhor opção, você tem que passar apenas o ID e na página de inserir os dados você consulta o registro pra saber se ele existe, caso não, você pode exibir alguma mensagem de erro, neste caso ficaria assim:

```
<a href="adicionatel.php?id=<?=$id?>" class="btn btn-success">Adicionar telefone de contato</a>
```

e na adicionatel.php :

```
$selbanco = "SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'];
```